# Weird behaviour when finetuning Huggingface Bert model with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to fine tune a Huggingface Bert model using Tensorflow (on ColabPro GPU enabled) for tweets sentiment analysis. I followed step by step the guide on the Huggingface website, but I am experiencing a weird training time. This happens with all the Bert models I tried.
I have two datasets of different sizes (10k and 2.5Millions) consisting of tweets that I need to classify as having a positive sentiment or a negative sentiment.

With this piece of code I perform tokenization of my dataset:

```
# perform tokenization of the dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

def tokenize_function(sentence):
    return tokenizer(sentence['Phrase'], padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=30)

train = train.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
test = test.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
val = val.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
```

I then create tensoflow datasets:

```
# go from 'Dataset' type to tensorflow so that our dataset can be used for training in keras
from transformers import DefaultDataCollator

data_collator = DefaultDataCollator(return_tensors="tf")

tf_train_dataset = train.to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=["Label"],
    shuffle=False,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=256,
)

tf_val_dataset = val.to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=["Label"],
    shuffle=False,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=256,
)

tf_test_dataset = test.to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
    shuffle=False,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=256,
)
```

Download and compile the model:

```
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification

# download pre-trained model
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME, num_labels=2)

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(),
)
```

And I finally train the model

```
# Compute some variables needed to speed up training
batch_size = 64
train_steps_per_epoch = int(len(tf_train_dataset) // batch_size)
dev_steps_per_epoch = int(len(tf_val_dataset) // batch_size)

# train model
model.fit(tf_train_dataset,
           validation_data=tf_val_dataset,
            epochs=1,
            verbose=2,
            # steps_per_epoch=train_steps_per_epoch,
            # validation_steps=dev_steps_per_epoch,
            )
```

I first trained this model on the 10K dataset and one epochs takes around 20mins. To me this is a lot. The training set is not that big and I am using a rather powerful GPU. I tried searching the web for some  tricks to speed up the trainig time and a guy on stackoverflow suggested setting the `steps_per_epoch` parameter, which I set to what you can see in the code. Now the trainig time improves exponentially, I can train the model on the full dataset (2.5M) for 3 epochs in 30mins, but the performance actually decrease. I loked up the definition of `steps_per_epoch` and to me it is almost like batch_size.

My questions now would be:

1. is it normal for a bert model to take 20mins for one epoch on a datatset of 10k tweets?
2. what does `steps_per_epoch` actually do? why does it speed up the training time so much? and why does the performance actually decrease?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question i haven't used the bert model before so i can't say.

For your second question well from what I understand, steps per epoch is the number of sample batches that will be used to fit the model during 1 epoch.

So let's say your number of epochs was 2 instead of 1 and you set your steps per epoch to 10 once the model is fitted with 10 batches of your training data (*in your case the batch size is set to 64, which is 640 samples per epoch*) it will end that epoch and start the second epoch which will also end after receiving 640 samples. So in the end the model is only trained with about 1280 samples of the data.

Although in your case you set your steps per epoch to the length of your entire sample size so it is strange that it reduced the training time. I will try something similar to understand what is going on.